# How to create a new language in Hybris?

Tags: localization, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I have added a new Language by going to Internationalisation -> Languages and then added a new language. But that language does not show up on the login page of Backoffice. It is present in the database, I can find it using flexible search.
Please can someone guide me, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a language in Backoffice, you need to define it in local.properties using the `lang.packs` property. e.g `lang.packs=en,de,newCode`.

However, this is not so simple or straight-forward. You would also need to localize the different UI texts and to update Solr configuration. Unfortunately, SAP does not provide a guide on this. There used to be one for Hybris 5, but it isn't available anymore. Unless absolutely needed, I suggest to forget about adding a new language for Backoffice.

**References:**

- Backoffice Login Page: https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/2011/en-US/3c97f2858f0b4ec7b9949a4801612744.html
- Data Locales and UI Locales Selection: https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/2011/en-US/f3578543ebf64a4688db813a37aa4adb.html